# xpages property file vs administration menu for dropdown list

Tags: xpages

What is the best practice for populating **dropdown** lists in case of XPages application:

1. the list items managed in the administration menu and displayed using **@DbColumn/@DbLookup**
2. the list items stored in property files and retrieved using SSJS

For better performance which can be the preferred solution in case of:

1. n. of list items<10
2. n. of list items<100
3. n. of list items<1000
4. n. of list items<10000

Comment: Don't forget No.3: Using of *view.getEntriesByKey* instead of @Functions to avoid 64k limitation. And the other ways with managed beans, scoped variables, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither nor!
A VERY smart way is to have one (or two) beans that hold all the properties you would be eventually looking for. If that are global values an applicationScope is the right place. For user specific ones it is the sessionScope. Your value population will be easy in the XPage: `AppSetup.departments` (that is EL code, not SSJS!) where **AppSetup** is the managed bean name and **departments** translates into .getDepartments();

You can start with a simple lookup inside the bean and later add caching and alternate storage (e.g. a MIMEDoc) as you deem fit. Since your "contract" are the public methods you can optimize internally to your hearts desire.

Here is a SSJS version of the [caching lookup](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8DFBNZ), but you want to go for the bean since it allows you to use EL which adds a little extra speed.

One remark: you know that a kitten must die every time a dropdown list has more than 100 entries. That so NOT suitable for UX. For large values use a grid with search capabilities or other UX elements.

Comment: In case of uisng managed beans where to store the list items? Inside the java code? How to maintain the list?
What does kitten mean? And what does UX element mean? Sorry for the lot questions, but I am new to managed beans.

Comment: You can store the list items in a view and let the bean retrieve the data from the view one time. In the bean you have a hashmap which contians the key and the value (name of the item)

Comment: Kitten = young cat; UX = User eXperience. The remark was aimed at the user interface design, not the code. Dropdown list with hundreds or more entries are a pain to use. Don't impose that on your users. Use the OpenNTF picklist instead

Comment: I would store the items (as @jjtbsomhorst suggested) in a view and load them once into the bean. You probably would have a HashMap<String,Collection> in the bean, so one lookup will give you all values

Comment: @stwissel Would not be better to store the items in java property files instead of view for performance reason, even there is only one lookup?

Comment: Nope if you take the performance hit of updating your configuration values. In a view: change the values, reset the bean. In a property file: NO easy mechanism, you need to redeploy